# Como pegar o id de uma Elemento HTML usando Javascript Puro

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso retorna o id de uma formulário Html, até ai tudo bem eu sei a função, porém a questão é quando o formulário tem um imput com name='id', ao inves de retornar o id do formulário a mesma função retorna o imput.
Preciso mesmo é do ID do formulário só.
*Obs nao posso remover o imput name='id', isso funciona porém preciso dessa informação.

```js
function enviar(evento, form){
  evento.preventDefault();
  
  // cosole log retorna name="id", preciso do id do Fomulario == idFormulario1 / idFormulario2 --///
  console.log(form.id); 
  
  const formularioID = form.id;
  const formularioCompleto = document.querySelector('#'+formularioID);
  const div = document.querySelector('#mostrarID');
  
  console.log(form);
  div.innerHTML = formularioID;
}
```

```html
<form action="./" method="post" id="idFormulario1" onsubmit="enviar(event,this)" >
<!-- Preciso dessa informação name=id, porém isso está atrapalhado !-->
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="777">

<input type="text" name="teste" id="teste" placeholder="da Erro">
<button type="submit">Descrobri ID Formulario 1 </button>
</form>


<br>
<hr>

<form action="./" method="post" id="idFormulario2" onsubmit="enviar(event,this)" >
<!-- Removendo name='id' funciona
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="777">
!-->

<input type="text" name="teste" id="teste" placeholder="Correto">
<button type="submit" >Descrobri ID Formulario 2 </button>
</form>


<br>
<br>
<div id='mostrarID'> </div>
```

Comment: Realmente vai ocorrer este comportamento Kleuton pq quando tem um elemento `Html` com o atributo **name** aquele elemento no caso aí um `input` vai ser reconhecido no documento exatamente com esse nome de **id**, aí quando faz **`form.id`** seria o mesmo que fazer **`form >> input`**, por isso o erro!

Comment: é realmente viz uma fasta pesquisa aqui, mas a unica solução foi mudar o input name=id, para outro nome, tipo name='id-qualquercoisa' ... valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, como comentei o que ocorre é que atribuindo o valor **id** ao atributo `name` o elemento que possui este atributo ficará reconhecido no documento `HTML` com esse nome e quando faz **`form.id`** na função ocorre o erro, pq é buscado o elemento com exatamente esse nome e não o id do formulário em si. O que pode fazer é como no exemplo abaixo, acessando o elemento *acima/pai* com a propriedade [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) e pegando o valor do atributo id deste elemento no caso aí o `form` através do método [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/element/getAttribute):

```js
function enviar(evento, form) {
  evento.preventDefault();

  const formularioID = form.id.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
  const div = document.querySelector('#mostrarID');

  div.innerHTML = formularioID;
}
```

```html
<form action="./" method="post" id="idFormulario1" onsubmit="enviar(event, this)">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="777">

  <input type="text" name="teste" id="teste" placeholder="UM">
  <button type="submit">Descrobri ID Formulario 1 </button>
</form>

<br>
<hr>

<form action="./" method="post" id="idFormulario2" onsubmit="enviar(event, this)">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="888">


  <input type="text" name="teste" id="teste" placeholder="DOIS">
  <button type="submit">Descrobri ID Formulario 2 </button>
</form>

<br>
<br>
<div id='mostrarID'> </div>
```